# Determine the number of people who only chose A.

Tags: combinatorics

I made a venn diagram to visualize this question better, i'm not sure i know how  to isolate A on its own to find out how many people chose the door.

A game show has three doors labelled A, B, and C behind which there may or may not be a prize. A group of contestants were asked which doors they think there is a prize behind. The results were:

A total of 18 people chose A, a total of 19 people choose B, and a total of 19 people choose  C. Also, 4 people chose both A and B, 7 people chose both A and C, 10 people chose both B and C, and 3 people chose all three.

a) Determine the number of people who only chose A.

Comment: Use venn diagram and mark each intersection separately.  You have all the values to get your answer.

Comment: yea but i don't know how to do that, do i add all the values together to get my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Draw three circles for your Venn diagrams. Label them as A, B, C.

The very middle of the diagram is the intersection of all three circles, and it represents those people that chose all of A, B, and C. Write "$3$" there, since $3$ people chose A, B, and C.

Next, fill in the three regions that represent the intersections of any two circles. Part of these intersections are now filled in (you just put a "$3$" in the very middle). Fill those remaining parts; you should write "$4$", "$1$", and "$7$" in them (you should be able to see which goes where). You can now ignore the rest of circles B and C!

Finally, you are asked to find the total number of people who chose *only* A. Well, based on what you've filled in so far, you should get
$$
\begin{aligned}[t]
(\text{# A only}) &= (\text{# A total}) - (\text{# A, B, and C}) - (\text{# A and B, not C}) - (\text{# A and C, not B}) \\
&= 18 - 3 - 1 - 4 \\
&= 10.
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer: $10$.

Comment: Notice that some information that was given to us was not even used at all.